# Why is my solution to $A^TCAx = f$ different by $7/8$ in my book?

Tags: linear-algebra

The first part of question 9 in chapter 8.2 of [Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232716) asks:

> With conductances $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = c_3 = 2$, multiply matrices to
>   find $A^TCA$. For $f = (1, 0, -1)$ find a solution to $A^TCAx = f$.

Given

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I get

$$
A^TCA = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 & -2 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 \\
-2 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
[A^TCA \quad f] = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 & 0 \\
-2 & -2 & 4 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 3/8 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1/8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
x = \begin{bmatrix}
3/8 \\ 1/8 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
c \\ c \\ c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The book gives this solution instead:

$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
5/4 \\ 1 \\ 7/8
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
c \\ c \\ c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand that the particular solution shifts the nullspace by a vector for which there are infinite possibilities but I'm wondering if the solution in the book might actually be specific to the second part of the question:

> Write the potentials $x$ and currents $y = -CAx$ on the triangle graph,
>   when the current source $f$ goes into node 1 and out from node 3.

Is there something in the question that somehow justifies adding $7/8$ to each component of my solution?

Comment: If $C$ is a column, $A^\top CA$ is not a valid matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife, thanks for the comment, the book defines $C$ as a "conductance matrix" where $c_i$ are on the diagonal; I fixed my question.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is singular, the sum of the first and third rows is the second row. i have no way of knowing what conductance is about, but it is illegal in quadratic forms to do this. In brief, $\det A = 0.$

Comment: You ought to say what the book is and define terms. If this really is about electricity or the like, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @WillJagy, when you say "it is illegal in quadratic forms to do this", to do what exactly?

Comment: I found a solution to some other problem by the same people. Evidently $A$ is an incidence matrix for a directed graph, which explains the entires $1,0,-1.$ The four by four example has $A$ quite definitely singular, they find the null space, so I guess that is part of this business. Not familiar.

Comment: examples suggest a consistent rule such as: row sums are always zero. Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node potentials are determined only up to an arbitrary additive constant, which cancels when you compute the voltage drops $\mathbf V=-\operatorname{d}\mathbf\Phi=-Ax$. This reflects the fact that the Laplacian of a connected weighted graph, which is what $A^TCA$ is here, has a one-dimensional kernel spanned by the vector of all ones. Both your solution and the book’s solution are consistent with this and describe the same solution set. (What Strang is essentially having you do in this exercise is solve Poisson’s equation $\Delta u=-\rho$ for this resistive network.)

I don’t see any particular advantage to setting the potential of the interior node (node 2) to 1, which is effectively what the book’s particular solution does. In fact, I prefer the particular solution that you came up with since it corresponds to grounding the current sink (node 3).